# Save own fields in database

Tags: 6, forms, nodes

i've altered a form by adding my own fields. they're not part of the node.
i'm wondering which hook to use, to save these fields in the db.

i guess hook_nodeapi is the right one, but the form variable only gets transfered in the 'validate' $op, and it doesn't seem right to save data in the validate operation.

So how would i go about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you alter a node editing form, the fields you add *are* part of the node and can be accessed using the **$node** argument of **hook_nodeapi**. Save your data when **$op == 'insert'** and **$op == 'update'**.

If you do not want your fields to become part of the node, write a form submit handler and add its name to the **$form['#submit']** array. The submit handler should remove all your fields from **$form_state['values']** (in addition to whatever was intended when adding the field to the form).

Answer (score 1):

with CCK module http://drupal.org/project/cck you can add your own fields to your content types, and each field will be stored in the database. CCK is a common module to create your own custom fields easily, see the documentation http://drupal.org/node/101723, .

Comment: thanks, i do know cck. it just doesn't fit in my use-case here